# Which form of lay to be used?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, lie-lay-lain-laid

I wrote a review of the movie ***Detroit*** [in my blog](https://moviefreakindia.wordpress.com) and in the section *What irked me about the film*, I started in the following fashion: -

*No doubt, Detroit is an engrossing flick, its greatest problem **lied** in the fact that it runs much longer than it should have.*

A friend of mine pointed out that it should be *lay* instead of **lied**. I'm confused as to which form is correct and why? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: ... **its** greatest problem..

Comment: The lay chicken lay on the floor laying a egg, while the preacher chicken gave his sermon titled "The Lay of the Land".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend is right, the past of lie (as in to recline) is lay. You've used the past of lie (to tell an untruth).

[This simple table might help you.](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54bff50ce4b0d9cac9375050/t/5775ac9ae4fcb56c633ae947/1467329696018/?format=750w)

However, since you've used the present tense for the rest of the sentence, you may want to use 'lies' instead.

Comment: Good table. The only slight reservation I have is with the past participle "lain". Nowadays that often becomes "laid", certainly in dialect form in the UK. The Queen would undoubtedly say "lain".

Comment: Hmm. "I'd lain down for a rest.", "I'd laid down for a rest." I think I'd have used the first one :/

Comment: But where do you call home? As I said, "in most UK dialects"... But the Queen's English says "lain".

Comment: Birmingham, UK. :D and I agree that a lot of people would say laid instead of lain, I was just thinking what I'd say

Comment: Bet you don't live in Aston or Sparkhill! You sound like a Solihull chap to me!

Comment: I went to school in Aston, but I'm from Sutton Coldfield. What about you?

Comment: Thank you @millman97 for the table and the explanation. ^_^

Comment: That figures. I'm an old Norfolk boy, from the deepest part of the county. And when I first went to grammar school in Norwich in 1954, before they taught me *to speak proper*, I thought the past-tense of "snow" was "snew", and of "drive" - "driv".

Comment: I like snew. Language is constantly evolving, maybe one day snew will make it into the dictionary XD

Comment: @millman97 My father used it until the day (almost) he died aged 99 yrs and 9 months in 2014.

Comment: I suppose I should've said 'back into the dictionary' :)